# Construct a triangle given certain lengths related to a bisector

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Let $ABC$ be a triangle, and $AD$ the bisector of angle $A$. Write $AB = c$, $AC = b$, $AD = d$, $BD = c'$, $CD = b'$. Using ruler and compass, construct the triangle $ABC$ given the lengths $d$, $b-b'$ and $c - c'$. (That is, we are given segments of lengths $d$, $b-b'$ and $c-c'$ to work with, and the problem is to reconstruct the triangle from these data.)

[image: Figure]

I already have an analytic solution to the problem that can be translated into a lengthy construction. I am looking for a geometric solution which is as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1) line $AX=x,AY=y,AN=d ,J $ is midpoint of $XY, M $is midpoint of $AX$,

2)circle $J @r=JY,AK \perp AX$, cross circle$J$ at $K$

3)make rectangle$AKQN$, connect $AQ, KL \perp AQ$ , cross $AQ$ at $L$

4) connect $ML,QB$//$ML$ cross $AN$ at $B$

5)circle $B@r=XB$, circle $A@r=AN$, two circle cross at $D$

6)circle $D@r=DN$, cross circle $A@r=AN$ at $P$

7)connect $BD,AP$, cross at $C$

$\triangle ABC$ is the wanted. note $AN> AK$ is necessary condition.

the proof is to OP.

edit: the op comments remind me that there is more simple way to build $AB$
[image]

$AG=\dfrac{d^2}{x}+y$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let $x = c-c'$, $y = b-b'$. $AK = \sqrt{xy}$, $AQ = \sqrt{d^2 + xy}$, $AQ/AL = AQ^2/AK^2 = (d^2 + xy)/xy$, $AB = AM \cdot AQ/AL = (x/2) \cdot (d^2 + xy)/xy = \frac{1}{2}(d^2/y + x)$. Analytically (using Stewart's Theorem and $x/y = c/b$), we get $c = \frac{1}{2}(d^2/y + x)$, so the length $AB$ is correct. Once $B$ has been placed, the construction is easy because all three sides of triangle $ABD$ are known. I agree that this solution works, but can you give a geometric motivation for it?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I assume that $\angle BAC$ is also given. Let $AX = x = b – b’$ and $AY = y = c – c’$. By angle bisector theorem, x : y = b’ : c’.

(1). Construct the circle $\alpha$ (centered at A, radius = d).

(2) Locate $B_1$ (exterior to ⊿ABC) on $\alpha$ such that $\angle B_1AB = \angle BAD$. $C_1$ is similarly constructed.

(3) B and C will be somewhere on the perpendicular bisectors of $B_1D$ and $C_1D$ respectively.

(4) B and C will be somewhere on the perpendicular bisectors of $B_1Y$ and $C_1X$ respectively.

(3) and (4) determine length and location of the line BC.

Comment: Do you get the impression this can possibly be turned into a complete solution?

Comment: Why are $B_1$ and $C_1$ needed? Wouldn't $B$ be the intersection of the perpendicular bisector of $YD$ with one of the sides of the angle?

Answer (score 0):

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle,  and $AD$ the bisector of angle $A$.  Write
>   $|AB|=c$, $|AC|=b$, $|AD|=d$,  $|BD|=c'$, $|CD|=b'$.  Using ruler and
>   compass,  construct the triangle $ABC$  given the lengths $d$,
>   $b-b'=u$ and $c-c'=v$.  (That is, we are given segments of lengths
>   $d$, $b-b'=u$  and $c-c'=v$ to work with,  and the problem is  to
>   reconstruct the triangle from these data.)

[image]

A line $\mathcal{L}_1$ through an arbitrary point $D$.

Points $\{A,D_2\}=\mathcal{C}_1(D,d)\cap\mathcal{L}_1$.

Point  $D_3=\mathcal{C}_2(D_2,d)\cap\mathcal{L}_1$.

Points $\{p_1,p_2\}=\mathcal{C}_3(D_3,|DD_3|)\cap\mathcal{C}_4(D,|DD_3|)$.

A line $\mathcal{L}_2$ through points $p_1,p_2$.

Point  $p_3=\mathcal{C}_4(D_2,v)\cap\mathcal{L}_2$.

Points $\{p_4,p_5\}=\mathcal{C}_5(p_3,|p_3p_2|)\cap\mathcal{C}_6(D,|p_3p_2|)$.

A line $\mathcal{L}_3$ through points $p_4,p_5$.

Point  $p_6=\mathcal{L}_2\cap\mathcal{L}_3$.

Point  $p_7=\mathcal{C}_7(p_6.|p_3p_6|)\cap\mathcal{L}_2$.

Point  $\{p_8,p_9\}=\mathcal{C}_8(p_7,u)\cap\mathcal{L}_2$.

Points $\{p_{10},p_{11}\}=\mathcal{C}_9(D_2,|D_2p_8|)\cap\mathcal{C}_{10}(A,|D_2p_9|)$.

A line $\mathcal{L}_4$ through points $A,p_{10}$.

A line $\mathcal{L}_5$ through points $A,p_{11}$.

Points $\{p_{12},p_{13}\}=\mathcal{C}_{10}(A,|D_2p_9|)\cap\mathcal{C}_{11}(p_{10},|D_2p_9|)$.

A line $\mathcal{L}_6$ through points $p_{12},p_{13}$.

Point  $C=\mathcal{L}_6\cap\mathcal{L}_4$.

A line $\mathcal{L}_7$ through points $C,D$.

Point  $B=\mathcal{L}_5\cap\mathcal{L}_7$.

A line $\mathcal{L}_1$ through an arbitrary point $D$.

Points $\{A,D_2\}=\mathcal{C}_1(D,d)\cap\mathcal{L}_1$.

Point  $D_3=\mathcal{C}_2(D_2,d)\cap\mathcal{L}_1$.

Points $\{p_1,p_2\}=\mathcal{C}_3(D_3,|DD_3|)\cap\mathcal{C}_4(D,|DD_3|)$.

A line $\mathcal{L}_2$ through points $p_1,p_2$.

Point  $p_3=\mathcal{C}_4(D_2,v)\cap\mathcal{L}_2$.

Points $\{p_4,p_5\}=\mathcal{C}_5(p_3,|p_3p_2|)\cap\mathcal{C}_6(D,|p_3p_2|)$.

A line $\mathcal{L}_3$ through points $p_4,p_5$.

Point  $p_6=\mathcal{L}_2\cap\mathcal{L}_3$.

Point  $p_7=\mathcal{C}_7(p_6.|p_3p_6|)\cap\mathcal{L}_2$.

Point  $\{p_8,p_9\}=\mathcal{C}_8(p_7,u)\cap\mathcal{L}_2$.

Points $\{p_{10},p_{11}\}=\mathcal{C}_9(D_2,|D_2p_8|)\cap\mathcal{C}_{10}(A,|D_2p_9|)$.

A line $\mathcal{L}_4$ through points $A,p_{10}$.

A line $\mathcal{L}_5$ through points $A,p_{11}$.

Points $\{p_{12},p_{13}\}=\mathcal{C}_{10}(A,|D_2p_9|)\cap\mathcal{C}_{11}(p_{10},|D_2p_9|)$.

A line $\mathcal{L}_6$ through points $p_{12},p_{13}$.

Point  $C=\mathcal{L}_6\cap\mathcal{L}_4$.

A line $\mathcal{L}_7$ through points $C,D$.

Point  $B=\mathcal{L}_5\cap\mathcal{L}_7$.

The sought triangle is $\triangle ABC$.

**EDIT**

Basic idea is to construct $\triangle ADC$ 
on given base $AD=d$
using the analytic solution 
$|AC|=b=\tfrac12\left( \frac{d^2}{v}+u \right) $ 
and $|DC|=b'=b-u$.

It seems to be easier to construct 
$\triangle AD_2p_{10}$ with doubled sides first and then 
construct point $C$ as a middle of $Ap_{10}$.

The point $p_{10}$ 
is constructed as intersection of 
circles with sides
$|D_2p_9|=2b=\frac{d^2}{v}+u$ 
and
$|D_2p_8|=2b'=\frac{d^2}{v}-u$.

Since $AD$ is the bisector of $\angle CAB$,
the line through $A,B$ (or through $A,p_{11}$) is symmetric to
the line through $A,C$ with respect to $AD$,
thus the point $B$ is found at 
the intersection of lines through $C.D$ and $A,p_{11}$.

The key question is then to construct a length $|D_2p_7|=\frac{d^2}v$
by means of a circle through three points, $D,D_3$ and $p_3$,
where we have $d^2=|DD_2|\cdot|D_2D_3|=|D_2p_3|\cdot|D_2p_7|=v\cdot \frac{d^2}v$.
The center of the circle 
is the intersection of the midpoint perpendicular to $Dp_3$
with the line through $p_1,p_2$, 
and point $p_7$ is obviousely found at the intersection
of the circle and line through $p_1,p_2$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It's hard for me to tell what's going on. Can you give the main ideas behind the construction?

Comment: @David: see the basic idea explained.

Answer (score 0):

a more nice method to rebuild the triangle:

[image]

$AD=d,AK=c-c',AJ=b-b', F $ is mid point of $AD$

1) circle $F@r=AF$,circle $A@r=AK$,circle $A@r=AJ$, three circles cross at $K_1,J_1$

2)$PQ \perp AD, AK_1$ cross $PQ$ at $P$,cross circle $AJ$ at $J_2, AJ_1$ cross $PQ$  at $Q$, cross circle $AK$ at $K_2$

3) take midpoint $M$ of $QK_2$, midpoint $N$ of $PJ_2$, connect $MN$ ,cross $AD$ at $I$

4)circle $I@r=ID$, cross circle $AK$ at $K_3$,cross circle$AJ$ at $J_3$

5)circle $A@r=AM,A@r=AN$, connect $AK_3$ cross circle $AM$ at $B$, connect $AJ_3$ , cross circle $AN$ at $C$.

$\triangle ABC$ (or $\triangle AB_1C_1$) is the one wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $b > c$ (hence also $b' > c'$ and $b - b' > c - c'$, since $b'/b = c'/c$).

Let $I$ be the incenter of $ABC$, and $J$, $K$, $L$, its projections onto $BC$, $AC$ and $AB$ respectively. Write $e = AK = AL$, $f = DJ$, $d_1 = AI$, $d_2 = ID$.

Then I claim (proofs given below) that:

- $e = \frac{1}{2}[(b - b') + (c - c')]$,
- $f = \frac{1}{2}[(b - b') - (c - c')]$,
- $d_1 + d_2 = d$,
- $d_1^2 - d_2^2 = e^2 - f^2 = (b - b')(c - c')$.

**Construction.** We first construct the length $e$ in the obvious way, and then $f = e - (c - c')$. Now we construct a right triangle with hypotenuse $e$ and one leg $f$, hence its other leg is $g = \sqrt{e^2 - f^2} = \sqrt{d_1^2 - d_2^2}$.

To construct the length $d_1$, we draw a right triangle with legs $d$ and $g$. The intersection of the bisector of the hypotenuse and the leg of length $d$ divides that leg into segments of length $d_1$ and $d_2$.

Hence we can now construct points $A, I, D$, with $I$ between $A$ and $D$ and $AI = d_1$, $ID = d_2$. We obtain points $K$ and $L$ as the intersections of of the circle with diameter $AI$ and the circle centered at $A$ with radius $e$. Thus we have constructed $\angle A$.

To complete the construction, we take $J$ to be the intersection of the circle with diameter $ID$ and the circle centered at $D$ of radius $f$. Then $DJ$ is the remaining side of the triangle.

**Proof of the claims.** It is well-known that $e = \frac{1}{2}(b + c - a)$, yielding the first claim. Likewise, the relation $BJ = \frac{1}{2}(a + c - b)$ leads to the second claim by writing $f = c' - BJ$. The third claim is obvious. The fourth follows by letting $r$ denote the inradius and writing $d_1^2 - e^2 = r^2 = d_2^2 - f^2$.

Answer (score 0):

This construction is longer than in my other answer, but more geometrically motivated.

Let $d, x = b - b', y = c - c'$ be the given lengths.

Since $b'/c' = b/c$ and $b' + c' < b + c$, we have $x, y > 0$.

Without loss of generality, we may assume $x \geq y$. Since $x/y = b/c$ it follows that $b \geq c$.

A necessary condition (by the triangle inequality) is $x = b - b' < d$. Assume therefore that $x < d$. We will see conversely that this is sufficient and that in this case there is a unique triangle that works.

**Analysis.** Let $I$ be the incenter and $J, K, L$ the points of contact of the incircle with sides $BC$, $AC$, $AB$, respectively. Denote he inradius by $r$ and write $a = BC = b' + c'$, $e = AK = AL$, $f = DJ$. We have

$e = \frac{1}{2}(b + c - a) = \frac{1}{2}[(b - b') + (c - c')] = \frac{1}{2}(x + y),$

$f = c' - BJ = c' - \frac{1}{2}(a + c - b) = \frac{1}{2}[(b - b') - (c - c')] = \frac{1}{2}(x - y) \geq 0$

Let $\Gamma$ be the circle of radius $e$ centered at $A$, and $\Gamma'$ the (possibly degenerate) circle of radius $f$ centered at $D$. Then the radii $IJ = IK = IL = r$ of the incircle are respectively tangent to $\Gamma$ at $K$, to $\Gamma$ at $L$ and to $\Gamma'$ at $J$ (when $f > 0$). Thus $I$ has equal power $r^2$ with respect to $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$. Therefore $I$ is the intersection of $AD$ and the radical axis of $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$.

Lastly, $J$, $K$ and $L$ are determined as points of contact of tangents to $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ from $I$. The sides of $ABC$ are the lines $AK, AL, DJ$. (When $f = 0$, we have $J = D$ and the remaining side is the perpendicular to $AD$ through $D$. When $f > 0$, there are two choices of $J$, but they result in triangles congruent via reflection about $AD$.)

**Construction.**

1. **Let $AD$ be a segment of length $d$.**
2. **Construct segments of length $e = \frac{1}{2}(x + y)$ and $f = e - y = \frac{1}{2}(x - y)$.**
3. **Construct circle $\Gamma$ of radius $e$ with center $A$ and circle $\Gamma'$ of radius $f$ with center $B$.** (Since $e + f = x < d$, the circles are outside each other.)
4. **Construct a point $M$ on the radical axis of $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$.** Draw an arbitrary circle, with centre not on $AD$, which intersects each of $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$. Let $M$ be the intersection of the secants to $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ determined by the four points of intersection.
5. **Construct the radical axis** by either: (1) drawing the perpendicular to $AD$ through $M$, or (2) constructing a second point $M'$ of the radical axis as in point 4, and then drawing $MM'$.
6. **Construct the point $I$ of intersection of the radical axis with $AD$.** (Since $I$ is on the radical axis, it has equal power with respect to each circle and it lies outside them.)
7. **Construct the points of intersection $K$ and $L$ of $\Gamma$ and the circle with diameter $AI$.** (These exist because $I$ is outside $\Gamma$ and $A$ inside. Segments $IK = IL$ are tangent to $\Gamma$ at $K$ and $L$, respectively.)
8. **Draw the circle $\Gamma''$ with center $I$ passing through $K$ and $L$. Let $J$ be its point of intersection with $\Gamma'$ that is on the same side of $AD$ as $L$.** (Since $I$ is on the radical axis of $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$, the length of a tangent from $I$ to $\Gamma'$ is equal to $IK$. Hence $J$ exists, and $IJ$ is tangent to $\Gamma'$ at $J$ if $f > 0$. Circle $\Gamma''$ is tangent to $AK$ at $K$, to $AL$ at $L$ and, if $f > 0$, to $DJ$ at $J$.)
9. **Take the sides of triangle $ABC$ to be the lines $DJ$, $AK$ and $AL$.** (If $f = 0$, then $J = D$; instead of $DJ$ take the tangent to $\Gamma''$ at $D$. In either case, $\Gamma''$ is tangent to all three lines. No two of the three lines can be parallel; in particular, $DJ$ and $AK$ cannot be parallel because the inequality $e > f$ precludes the possibility that $J$ and $K$ are diametrically opposite in $\Gamma''$.)

It follows from the construction that triangle $ABC$ has incircle $\Gamma''$, and that its points of contact with the sides are $J, K, L$. Line $AD$ passes through the incenter $I$, hence it is indeed a bisector. By construction, we have $AD = d$, $AK = AL = e = (x + y)/2$ and $DJ = f = (x - y)/2$. Hence by the previous analysis

$b - b' = AC - CD = e + f = x, \qquad c - c' = AB - BD = e - f = y,$

as required.